# Is it possible to convert separated flow back to attached?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, drag, aerodynamics, turbulence

Sometimes you cannot easily create ideal single streamlined shape...

**Would it be possible to attach separated flow again somehow?**

The point is - you have some **base** setup (average **cyclist**) and want to **improve drag** without too big or heavy construction changes.

*I am* **intentionally asking here**, *because there are not many scientists on bicycle site and saw lot of strange attempts that were either banned by UCI or there is probably no clear evidence or proof of drag improvement.*

Hope no one would like to spend 30 years improving something to possibly find dead end road.

For example can something like this **in theory** bring any significant drag improvement?
[image: Example from discussion group]

Comment: Found some thoughts here https://www.bentrideronline.com/messageboard/showthread.php?t=160298 too.

Comment: Your title is more specific than the question, which seems to essentially be "How can I streamline a human powered vehicle?", which is too general. The title seems to be asking if an object inserted into turbulent flow can convert it back to laminar flow, which I think involves some interesting physics. More details help. Are you interested only in air drag, or water drag? (You mention bicycles, but there are lots of human powered watercraft, e.g. canoes.) Are you interested in specific speeds?  None of that guarantees you'll get an answer, but it increases the chance.

Comment: You may want to try asking this question over on [bicycles stack exchange](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I agree with @DavidBailey that if you ask whether it is possible to "laminarize", with proper apologies to English grammarians, a turbulent flow then it is a *very* interesting question, so I suggest you ask that way and I am sure it will be reopened.

Comment: Are you sure that the problem is to convert turbulent flow back to laminar? I suspect it's more likely (or more importantly, at least) to convert separated flow back to attached.

Comment: Thank you all, for comments. I was not sure how to express the point...

Comment: Before spending another 30 years, I would suggest getting some Computational Fluid Dynamics (CFD) software and modelling the drag for different configurations. There is a lot of commercial CFD software, and I believe [OpenFOAM](https://www.openfoam.com/) is  free and open source.  It will take some time to set up and learn, but once up to speed it should be a tremendous help in your design process.

Comment: Probably, but it is an example, not mine I checked few parts and found it is quite hard to find any difference, even smaller front area or more horizontal rider position can do way more... But have at least nice long horizontal fender extension still ;-) Anyway it is nice to search for new ways, but hard to find some reasonable and also materials, other components, etc. can consume your improvement. https://www.popsci.com/diy/article/2010-06/you-built-what-aerocycle/ or https://www.carscoops.com/2022/09/how-much-more-aerodynamic-can-you-make-your-car-with-a-trip-to-the-home-improvement-store/

Comment: everything you add toy your bike increases its weight and decreases its maneuverability. My suggestion: look at what the best bike manufacturers are going, like Pinarello

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to the question:

> Would it be possible to attach separated flow again somehow?

is yes. This phenomenon happens typically on airfoils which have a quite round leading edge and a medium thickness. Increasing the angle of attack a so called "separation bubble" forms on the upper surface of the airfoil. Inside the bubble the flow is separated (stalled) but before and after the bubble the flow is attached. Increasing the angle of attack the bubble extends backward until it separates quite abruptly.

The following picture taken from [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/307087525_Optimization_of_a_Human-Powered_Aircraft_Using_Fluid-Structure_Interaction_Simulations) depicts this effect:

[image: separation bubble]

Comment: Found simple JS CFD simulation, but original had complicated edit and not much shapes, my copy has also copy/paste implemented and few more predefined shapes https://eltomjan.github.io/JStoolsSPAdemos/fluids.htm